# How can I symlink source directories into a Cocoapods pod?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm building a library using Cocoapods (a Flutter plugin actually). For this, I need to reuse some existing source code from a different part of my repository directory structure and thought I'd create a symlink in my source directory. However, I can't get Cocoapods to add the files to my XCode project.

I've tried both:

```
s.source_files = 'Sources/**/*'
```

and

```
s.source_files = 'Sources/**/*', 'Sources/MySymlinkedCode/**/*'
```

How can I get Cocapods to take these files into account?

Cocoapods: 1.11.3